# How to allow "important" neurons

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gan

Let's say I have a generation task like a GAN or other method for next-frame video prediction, consisting of a 256x256x3x10 image sequence, plus a 1-hot vector of length 4.

If the result of the prediction actually depends 90% on the value of the 1-hot vector and 10% on the value of the 256x256 input, what kind of architecture should I use?  Should I just append the 4 "important" values to the rest at the lowest layer, and let the network figure out the importance, or should I add that vector near the "middle" (lowest dimentional representation) level of the GAN, or should I replicate each 1-hot value to a all on or all off 256x256 "channel"?

I'm wondering if DNNs are able to generally "locate extremely important inputs" or if some artifact of normalization limits the max influence of a neuron/input and we need to make sure the inputs are fed to just the right spot in the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A network will figure out which neurons are 'important' and which ones aren't by modifying the weights. This is not something you have to specify on your own.

So I assume you are using convolutional and pooling layers to handle your image. At the end of these layers, you will have a fully connected layer. As the vectors don't add any information to the image data, you have to add that 1-hot vector of length 4 at the fully connected layer at the 'end' of the network.